# BLT library TCL/TK

Tags: makefile, installation, tcl

I'm trying to install this library and i'm not being able accomplish this. I'm trying to install it through cygwin, I have tcl 8.5 and blt 2.5 the problem is when i run make command i get this error and can't seem to find the problem.

```
 $ make
(cd generic; make all)
make[1]: Entering directory `/lib/blt2.5/generic'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `pure_api.o', needed by `BLTlite25.dll'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/lib/blt2.5/generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Is that building from the source distribution linked from [here](http://pdqi.com/w/pw/pdqi/Wize/Blt)?

Comment: yeah exactly from there